# Code works in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, firefox

I have been working on a really large html form which has a reset button.
On reset, there is a database operation which takes place.

I have a javascript function as such, which is called on reset:

```
function clearDatabaseOfAnySavedForm() {
    window.name = 1;                        
    $.post('assets/scripts/reset-form.php');    
    window.location.reload();
    $(document).load().scrollTop(0);            
    return false;
}
```

The code for the php file referenced in this function is:

```
<?php
    //Authcate
    $authcate = xxxxx;  

    $username = "xxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxx";
    //$hostname = "xxxxx";  
    $hostname = "xxxxx";  
    $database = "xxxxx";
    $conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die( "Unable to select database");  

    if (!empty($authcate)) {        
        $table = "xxxxx";

        $sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE authcate = '$authcate'";
        $selectResults = mysql_query($sqlSelectQuery);
        $selectNumResults = mysql_num_rows($selectResults);
        if ($selectNumResults > 0) {
            $sqlUpdateQuery = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE authcate = '$authcate'";
            $result = mysql_query($sqlUpdateQuery);
        } 
    }
    mysql_close($conn); 
}
```

All this works fine is all browsers, but for some reason, the php file doesn't get invoked in Firefox. 
Does anyone have any ideas of suggestions?

Comment: You can always use the great and often updated $.browser function, and post a huge message if the user has Firefox "Please use Internet Explorer, this site is great !" ??

Comment: @adeneo that would by itself make the site not great at all...

Comment: do you use firebug? what error message are you seeing?

Comment: @adeneo: i am looking for a solution, not a workaround. thanks.

Comment: Firebug is your friend when debugging ajax calls in Firefox.  It allows you to watch everything going out/coming back, and troubleshoot where your error might be.  BTW, it's NOT Firefox's problem.

Comment: @landon: there is no error message coming up in firebug.

Comment: @user1792935 - your code does'nt make sense at all, that's why I suggested the rather stupid workaround!

Comment: @cale_b: are you sure it has nothing to do with some jquery (may be $.post access to the php script) compatibility with firefox?

Comment: @adeneo: why doesnt my code make sense? please elaborate.

Comment: I think @epascarello does it well enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @epascarello's answer, you probably want to use a callback function, this will execute code when your post is done.  Read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
function clearDatabaseOfAnySavedForm(){
  $.post('assets/scripts/reset-form.php', function(){
    //this will execute when the post returns
    window.location.reload();
  })
}
```

And you don't need the scrollTop and return false;

If you don't know what a callback function is, read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp).  I remember when I first started with javascript, it was a very unusual concept to grasp.

Comment: you saved my day bud! i actually did not realize that i was reloading before the request was sent.

Comment: Credits to @epascarello as well

Comment: yes, credit to him for pointing out the issues, i +1'ed his answer, sorry for the poach :)

Answer (score 6):

Your code is full of race conditions and impossible steps. I am surprised it would run in the other browsers.

```
function clearDatabaseOfAnySavedForm()
{
    window.name = 1;                        
    $.post('assets/scripts/reset-form.php'); <-- call server with asynchronous call  
    window.location.reload();  <-- reload page, it will cancel out the server call
    $(document).load().scrollTop(0); <-- um page is been reload, what does this do ?
    return false;  <-- page is reloaded, what are you cancelling?
}
```

Only way to make sure the code on the server is run is making sure the callback happens, than reload the page. The post request is asynchronous. There is no guarantee the browser will execute it. Most browsers will take any open connections when the page is exited and kill them. That is why Firefox is not executing it.

In firefox you are losing the race condition. The call is made and before it completes connecting to the server, the request is cut off so the browser can send the request to refresh the page. You need to wait for the request to make a connection with the server. You need to wait for the readyState to hit 2 at least.

BUT why even bother making an Ajax call, submit a post request to the page. The page will reload and redirect back to where you came from. Ajax is not the right solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @epascarello.
I basically do not care of what is returned from the server as i am performing a delete operation on my db. All i care is that the delete operation happens, but that itself is not happening. 
If ajax is not the right solution, what do you think is the right solution for my problem?

cheers

Comment: There's simply not enough time to send a request, as you're redirecting right away?

Comment: @user1792935 It does not matter if you care what comes back from the server, the client is not giving the request enough time to go out.